# Is there any convenient way to modify the field of a Rust struct while cloning it without unnecessarily cloning the field to be modified?

Tags: rust

I have some code which needs to modify a field of a struct during a clone. I want to avoid unnecessarily cloning that field before modifying it. The original struct is wrapped in an `Rc` so I can only access it via a reference. Here is a simplified example with a naive attempt to use the [struct update syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax):

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct B {
    value: i32,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct A {
    b: B,
    c: i32,
}

impl A {
    fn update_c(&self, c: i32) -> Self {
        A {
            c,
            ..*self
        }
    }

    fn update_b(&self, b: B) -> Self {
        A {
            b,
            ..*self
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(A {
        b: B { value: 0 },
        c: 0,
    });

    let a = Rc::new(a.update_c(-1));
}
```

[rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c480741eefb0830084159deac1181638)

Unfortunately this doesn't compile because my type does not implement `Copy`, and I don't really want it to implement `Copy`. I'm also guessing that in this case, the copy while performing the dereference in `..*a` would be just as expensive as cloning the entire struct before modification.

The only way I've found so far to make this work is to manually clone each field:

```rust
fn update_c(&self, c: i32) -> Self {
    Self {
        c,
        b: self.b.clone()
    }
}
```

[rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c685a137337b7ce8c67872631f69aff4)

But this would not be convenient for a struct with many fields. Is there a different solution or crate out there with a custom derive to have this functionality available for every field without having to exponentially increase the amount of code you write to add a new field?

Comment: If you could handle moving the value rather than copying then it would be possible to do what you want, however because you are taking self by reference Rust doesn't allow you to move out of it because someone else might have a reference to the same object

Comment: If you create a new `Rc` on every update you might as well not use `Rc` in the first place. You might be better off using [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html)

Comment: "Is there any convenient way to modify the field of a Rust struct while cloning it without unnecessarily cloning the field to be modified?" this doesn't mean any thing of it's me ?

Comment: I would do that https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7f13bdaf2b74a74a11a52b07c4552184, and no I do not know any crate that would do this for you, and language will not do it cause clone is explicit.

Comment: @Stargateur It's clumsily worded. It means to ask if there's a way to clone the struct except for a single field, whose value you already have (hence "modify the field of a struct while cloning it"). The OP wants to avoid `let new = self.clone(); new.field = <value>; new` because the `clone()` of the whole structure would "unnecessarily clone the field to be modified".

Comment: @user4815162342 yes you're right, I could have done a better job with the wording, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @Stargateur the solution you suggest still suffers from a similar problem in that I need to specify every field in the struct for every field that I want to be able to modify in this way. I wanted to find something with similar ergonomics to the struct initialization .. syntax

Comment: @msrd0 unfortunately for my use case, there may still be users of the struct still relying on the old data (pre-modification).

Comment: I think the chief question here is how expensive is the unnecessary `clone()`. If it just  operates in memory, there's a good chance that the compiler optimizes the call to `clone()` followed by assignment to the code that you want to write in the first place. Check the assembler output (with your actual code) to see whether this micro-optimization is even necessary.